# How to recruit a PhD student without a strong connection to teaching?

Tags: job-search, phd

As a postdoc, I'm considering to apply to research-only positions (for instance in a research institute, and not a university), and I know that one of the responsibilities of being a researcher is to recruit PhD students.

I personally only know people (including me) who have been "recruited" for a PhD by one of their teacher (usually at Master level), and so I wouldn't be sure of how to proceed in order to recruit a PhD student as a young researcher:

- Are there some specialized websites where to post ads?
- Is it better to contact some teachers to see if they have good students to recommend?

Moreover, in this case, which criteria can one use? If I were to teach, I would have a whole semester to know a student, and to decide whether it would make a good fit for a PhD, but how to do that during a one-hour interview?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PhD studentships are quite often advertised like "normal" jobs, i.e. on general job boards/recruting websites. If you have contacts, by all means use them. As for evaluating the candidates, similar guidelines as for evaluating applicants for any jobs apply. I don't think there's a one-fits-all answer. Note that the hiring process may also depend on what institution you'd be working for. They might have an HR department that screens/selects the candidates.

Comment: But somehow, it seems weird to evaluate applicants like for any other jobs. I mean, I have the feeling that the connection Phd-student/advisor is a bit different than staff member/boss, no? And how can you evaluate the ability of student to do research? I don't believe that high marks are necessarily a sign of being able to do adopt a research approach (I've seen some cases in the past).

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add that special considerations apply, but somehow missed that :)

Comment: What I meant in general is that you have to use indicators like examples of work, quality of proposal etc.

Comment: Would you have some tips on how to deal with those special considerations? :)

Comment: So, you actually ask for a proposal to the candidate? I was thinking of the case where I have a project and a (somehow) specific topic to work on, so you would ask a proposal on how the candidate would address this topic and work within this project?

Comment: I haven't done it myself, but I would look for evidence of voluntary involvement in activities that are connected to the proposed research, e.g. collaboration with faculty members that work in the area (e.g. in a final year project). Something else to watch out for is probably recommendations mentioning that the person is able to work independently.

Comment: I think I would prefer the candidate to at least contribute to the proposal so that I could assess their ability to write something scientific.

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple of ways to determine whether a particular graduate student is a good candidate for your lab.

- **Subject knowledge**. While this is often unfair to the student, I know many researchers who will only accept students who are familiar with their area of research. This saves time in getting the student up to speed, which can take many months, as you probably know.
- **Simple personality matches**. By the time they're looking into your lab, they've already been accepted into the graduate program and kept their grades up high enough to be applying to labs, which means that (assuming you agree with the standards of the program) they are fairly smart. Your job is determine whether the student would be a good match for your lab in particular, and whether you want to work with them on a daily basis for the next 5+ years.
- **Rotations**. Many programs have graduate student rotations, which will give you an opportunity to interact with many students, and get the chance to know them better than the one-hour interview you mentioned.

Aside from this, read up on general interviewing tips. Almost all the articles you'll find discussing general hiring advice is applicable to recruiting graduate students/postdocs as well.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, but I have to admit that I'm not really familiar with the concept of graduate program (my bad, I should have made explicit that I was thinking about Europe). So I'm not sure I could rely on the fact that the student has been already present. I'm going to look now for what is exactly a graduate program/school :)

Comment: By "graduate program", I simply mean your department. Faculty positions are tied to departments, and (in many departments) typically you'll be recruiting students who are already graduate students in your department. In my post, I was referring to students who were already accepted to the department.

Comment: Yes, I'm really not used to this concept of recruiting students who already are grad students in the department. I mean, in France, there is clear separation between Master and PhD, and you can't be in the doctoral school if you haven't found first a PhD advisor.

Answer (score 3):

I am presuming by your question that you are talking about working in Europe; in North America, scientists at non-academic research labs generally are not generally expected to recruit PhD students. Unfortunately, I don't think there is an easy method for applying for positions outside of posting announcements on sites like [academia.edu](http://www.academia.edu) or [TIPTOP](http://brightrecruits.com/tiptop/).

However, you will need to make sure that you are clear on your future workplace's requirements and regulations regarding the recruiting of graduate students. Many such institutes do *not* have PhD-granting programs of their own; in that case, you would need to make sure you were affiliated with a program that does grant doctoral degrees *before* you begin recruitment.

Comment: Thanks for the links, and yes, I was indeed thinking about working in Europe :)

Answer (score 2):

I can answer for a specific case: if you are looking to hire PhDs in Theoretical Computer Science, join the THEORYNT mailing list, where you can both send and receive mails about such vacancies. I'm giving an [example link](https://listserv.nodak.edu/cgi-bin/wa.exe?A2=ind1202a&L=theorynt&T=0&P=367) that would show you the typical format of such a mail, you can browse through the rest from the website itself.

If you look around, I'm sure there's be a mailing alias for your research specialty as well (if not, maybe you can start one!)

Comment: Thanks, I guess I would be considering something like that, I'm just wondering if with no prior experience in full supervising, it would be easy to recruit a student just through a classical ad/interview process.